# Ruby sort hash of hashes

Tags: ruby

I have a set of activities that I want to sort based on an average rating, and how many times the activity has been rated.

```
activities = {
  :one => { :avg_rating => 5, :total_ratings => 23 },
  :two => { :avg_rating => 5, :total_ratings => 18 },
  :three => { :avg_rating => 5, :total_ratings => 54 }
}
```

EDIT - updated so the results I was expecting was correct

The result of the sort would be in order of `:three, :one, :two`

Thanks!

Comment: What do mean by sorting based on average rating *and* number of ratings?  How do you break ties between two activities when one has a better average rating but the other has more total ratings?

Comment: Also, why would your list result in `:three, :two, :one`?  They all have the same average rating, and the `:three, :two, :one` is not the same order if you sorted by most total ratings.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
activities.sort_by { |k,v| 
  [v[:avg_rating], v[:total_ratings]] 
}.reverse
```

Whether you need the element names only:

```
activities.sort_by { |k,v| 
  [v[:avg_rating], v[:total_ratings]]
}.reverse.map &:first
#⇒ [
#  [0] :three,
#  [1] :one,
#  [2] :two
#]
```

Comment: Thanks. And I realised that put the wrong sort order result I was expecting in my question too - but you knew what I meant!!